# How to define variable sstring or function with params?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to define a variable like a string or like a Function, but with params.

I know that string is defined like that `actionGetData: string;`, the function can be defined like that `actionLoaded?(event: any, ui: any): void;`, but when I try to define a variable like a string or like a Function with specific params, I get an error.

```
actionToDoubleClick?: 'Details' | 'Edit' | 'Create' | (event: any, ui: any);
```

I can define the variable like `actionToDoubleClick?: 'Details' | 'Edit' | 'Create' | Function;`, but this code allow any function, and I need only function with two params.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend separating by types:

```
type FunctionType = (event: any, ui: any) => void;

type StringType = 'Details' | 'Edit' | 'Create';

actionToDoubleClick?: StringType | FunctionType;
```